# Django Login in Views

Tags: django

I'm trying to login user from views getting an error `'User' object has no attribute 'backend'`

```
from django.contrib.auth import login

def confirmation(request):
    ...
    user = User.objects.get(id=user_id)
    login(request, user)
```

Comment: You don't show how you're getting the `user` object, but you need to do so by calling `authenticate`.

Comment: show  complete view function.

Comment: I don't want to use authenticate because I'm using a confirmation code to automatically log in the user. I don't have the password.

Answer (score 0):

Got it just set `request.user = user`